# Update table on condition from another table Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a two tables

```
MovieStar (
    name: char(15),
    address:varchar(40),
    gender:char(1),
    birthdate: date,
    rating:float
)

StarsIn (
    movieTitle:char(25), 
    movieYear:int, 
    starname:char(15), 
    role:varchar(15)
)
```

`starName` is foreign key which is related to name of `MovieStar`.

I want to increment rating by one when `Starsin` record is inserted and role of the new record is 'main'

What it would do is;

```
on insert to starsin, check whether role = 'main'
if so, what is starname
increment rating of moviestar name = starname
```

Comment: what for: sql server, mysql, oracle, sybase ase, etc. ?

Comment: mysql, sorry for not mentioning before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not store the value `rating` in your table as it can be derived from the other table's data when it is required. And why are you using `float` for the count?

Create a `VIEW` which counts the rows in `Starsin`, based on your condition `role = 'main'` and then you have no need for the trigger and the count will always be up to date when new rows are added or removed.

With the trigger solution you also have to take account of row deletion to decrement the count.

**EDIT:** From the comment you made, here's a sample trigger (although the syntax may be wrong as I mainly work with SQL Server). I'm assuming the `name` field in the `MovieStar` table is a primary key and therefore unique.

```
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateRating AFTER INSERT ON StarsIn
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE MovieStar SET rating =
        (SELECT rating FROM MovieStar WHERE name = NEW.starname) + 1
    FROM MovieStar INNER JOIN NEW ON MoveStar.name = NEW.starname
    WHERE NEW.role = 'main'
END
```

I'm not familiar with MySQL, I work with SQL Server, where triggers need to be set based. I'm guessing the `FOR EACH ROW` part of the trigger means the statements are executed for each row inserted, but I may be wrong about that.

Comment: but above is the actual requirement, the rating column is newly added column and is already there, although not mentioned...Proc is in place to update the column.Trigger is what I need to update the table based on new records inserted to starsin table

Comment: @ghTvNath - If that's the design you have to work with, that's fine. I just wanted to suggest an alternative which would avoid the possible problem of `rating` becoming out of sync with the `Starsin` table. You say "Proc is in place to update the table" does that mean you just need to call the procedure from a trigger?

Comment: sorry what I am saying is dump, but I use the proc to update ratings of already inserted records of moviestar table.what I need a trigger is to update the table,when new records are inserted. what my idea is like this

     CREATE TRIGGER updaterank AFTER INSERT ON testish.`starsin`
     AS
     BEGIN
      IF role = 'main' THEN var newname = starname
     END
     FOR EACH ROW
      UPDATE `moviestar`
 SET `moviestar`.`name` = newname; 'code'

Answer (score 2):

You need to [`create a trigger on insert`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) and do the intended `update`.